# Angular 2 : Access Cookie after Creation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cookies

I have two Component and one Service

Components:

1: LoginComponent

2: HeaderComponent (Shared)

Service:

1: authentication.service

In LoginComponent I use authentication.service to get authenticate and after successful authentication, I add User info into the Cookie and in the end, I automatically navigate to return-URL page, in the returned page I have a Component for the header that must show User info from the saved Cookie, BUT there is nothing in the cookie unless I refresh manually the page with F5 button.

My question is how can I access the cookie without refreshing the page?

**Update**

this is where I want to get the cookie:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieHelper } from '../../_helpers/index';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'app-header-ichart',
templateUrl: 'header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
currentUser = '';
isLogged = false;
constructor(private cookie: CookieHelper) { }


ngOnInit() {
     this.isLogged = this.cookie.checkCookie('currentUser');
     if (this.isLogged) {
         this.currentUser = JSON.parse(this.cookie.getCookie('currentUser'));
     }
}
}
```

**Update 2**

I used your suggestion technic to achieve my goal but need more help:

I Update my AuthenticationService to serve Observable Variable:

**AuthenticationService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
import { CookieHelper } from '../_helpers/index';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  cookies: Object;
  keys: Array<string>;
  user$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private http: Http, private config: AppConfig, private cookie: CookieHelper) { }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let body = `grant_type=${'password'}&username=${username}&password=${password}`;
return this.http.post(
  this.config.apiUrl + '/token',
  body, { headers: headers })
  .map((response: Response) => {
    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
    let user = response.json();

    if (user && user.access_token) {
      user['username'] = username;
       // Observable Variable
      this.user$.next(JSON.stringify(user));

      // store user details and jwt token in cookie to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      this.cookie.addCookie('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
  });
  }

  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.user$.asObservable();
  }

  logout() {
// remove user from cookie to log user out
this.cookie.removeCookie('currentUser');
   // Logout Subscribe
this.user$.next(null);

  }
}
```

**HeaderComponent:**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
currentUser = '';
isLogged = false;
constructor(private cookie: CookieHelper, private auth: AuthenticationService) { }


ngOnInit() {
    // Get the currentUser from Observable Variable
    this.auth.getUser().subscribe(currentUser => { this.currentUser = currentUser; });
    console.log(this.currentUser);
     this.isLogged = this.cookie.checkCookie('currentUser');
     if (this.isLogged) {
         this.currentUser = JSON.parse(this.cookie.getCookie('currentUser'));
     }
}
}
```

Comment: is this behavior common in different browsers? If you run `document.cookie` in the browser console what do you get?

Comment: with the document.cookie i can get the cookie, the cookie exist but in my headerComponent it isn't load until i refresh the page

Comment: I Update my Question to get more specific

Comment: that's strange. If in your headerComponent `ngOnInit` you call `console.log(document.cookie)` you get nothing?

Comment: the headerComponent selector is placed in AppComponent to show in Entire Application

Comment: you did not answer my question...

Comment: @crash yes I didn't get anything and I guess because the ngOnInit is not triggered after every route navigation unless we refresh the page to call it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147801/discussion-between-crash-and-adnan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an `Observable` to achieve that. So your `headerComponent` will be notified after the login.

Update your `authentication.service` so that you have something like

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class AuthenticationService {
    user$: Subject<any>;

    login() {
      // login stuff
      this.user$.next('userDetails');
    }

    logout() {
      this.user$.next(null);
    }
}
```

and then from whatever component you want you can check for the `user$` observable.

In template with

```
{{ (user$ | async)?.username }}
```

or in code with

```
user$.subscribe(user => console.log(user.username))
```

Comment: this code return error: Cannot Read property of undefined

Comment: your comment is too generic for me to be able to help you, elaborate more on than or update your code

Comment: so: 1. you there's no need to stringify the user, 2. why are you using `this.user$.asObservable();` instead of simply `this.user$` ? 3. you will definetely get `' '` in your `console.log(this.currentUser);` since it is probably called before the subscribe method has completed. I'm in chat for 30 mins if you want, join me there and we'll fix it

Comment: Thanks, crash your solution is the key to solving my issue but I implementing it with a different scenario, i Used this article and implementing like that: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: Ok glad you found an article to point you in the right direction and finally solved your issue ;)